# Caching problem when searching for user:me

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Search appears to cache results for a short time. This is normally fine, since everyone sees the same results for the same query, but it causes oddness if the query includes `user:me`. For example, [BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) searched for `user:me [homework]` on SO, and I searched for the same thing a moment later. I got his cached results (with all of his posts) instead of a list of my own posts. After a minute or so the query switched to giving me no results at all, and then finally to showing my own results. Is it possible for queries containing `user:me` (or anything else that might return different results for different users, like mod-only filters) to not cache? Or for search to convert it to `user:UID` first so the query won't match someone else's

Comment: "Or for search to convert it to `user:UID` first so the query won't match someone else's" It is interesting to note that it already does this when displaying the search option in the sidebar. I imagine it'd be trivial to port this to the search field as well.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yeah, and when I tried searching for `user:309308 [homework]` I still got your results, so I'm not sure how search is coming up with that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key we were using for cache here was pre-replacement on the `user:me` to `user:12345`, in the next build this will be fixed.  Also, it'll be fixed for the similar `inquestion:this` case.