# Glitch when sorting questions by vote count

Tags: bug, status-norepro, sorting, information-display

*Related but different:* [Sorting questions by votes is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95408/sorting-questions-by-votes-is-broken)

That was about the order going off after exactly 1000 results, which is not the same as what I'm seeing.

---

On meta, I did this:

- Clicked Questions, and then [Votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes&pagesize=50). (My page size was already 50 results per page)
- Clicked the [last page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=638&sort=votes).
  Because I know there is a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed) with -105 votes, I expected to see it on the last page. **But it wasn't there:**

[image: Last question is missing]

- I then went back to the first page, and then to the second page. On the second page I scrolled down and came to this:

[image: huh?]

After 92 votes, everything went weird. Then it resumed normally from 91.

**EDIT**

I can reproduce this frequently now, like this:

Go to the [main page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Click [Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions). Click [votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes). Click `Next` until you get to a page that's messed up. The last few times I did this, it was page 4:

[image: Messed up sort order on page 4]

**And something else weird just happened.** While paging through the results, when I got to about page 4, *my view suddenly switched from 50 results per page to 15 results per page*. Maybe it's related.

Comment: Caching? Though it's quite a jump even for that.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120045/caching-problem-when-searching-for-userme) is tangentially related (although certainly not the same thing)?

Comment: I see that the 4th to 7th questions visible in my screenshot were all questions that wouold have been near the top of the "newest" sort order at that time. But the rest of the questions on the page (above and below what you can see in the screenshot) seemed to be sorted by votes. I'm having trouble imagining a query that would have returned the question list in that order.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman are you referring to [this question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99062/155556)

Comment: Yes. It's the only question with -105 votes.

Comment: @sarnold: It definitely doesn't happen every time. Why is the -105 question a beacon of hope? Because of it's (faux) naivete?

Comment: I have a feeling this might only happen if a question is asked or updated while you're paging through the sorted questions.

Comment: @sarnold: Do you mean [Questions missing from Highest Voted Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115813/questions-missing-from-highest-voted-questions)? It's [status-completed], but it seems to be the same issue.

Comment: @Dennis: yes! That's the one exactly. Thank you!

Comment: I don't disbelieve you, but it isn't happening now... :( or should that be :)